# Convert this to another color type?

Tags: colors, hex

So, this script that I am using uses colors like in the form of `0x333333`. All that I know are simple hex color codes, such as `#EEEEEE`. What would that color be in this weird format? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing weird about it.  That color in particular would be a shade of very light gray - close to white.

The way to read hex colors is that, starting from the left, you have a byte representing Red, a byte representing Green, and a byte representing Blue.

`0xEEEEEE` implies that you have a value of `0xEE` for red, `0xEE` for green, and `0xEE` for blue.  They're all the same so you won't get any distinct primary or secondary colors.

Comment: Ahhh so I just need to add a 0x? What is the deal with that?

Comment: *I* use `0x` to represent it as a hexadecimal value, which it is.  Most environments (that you place colors in hex) will assume you mean that when you put `#` in front of the hex value.

Answer (score 1):

Each byte (2 hex characters) in the string represents a colour component (red, green, or blue).  If each component is the same then you have a grayscale colour.  In the case of `EEEEEE`, it's almost white.

Generally, when we specify a colour using HTML syntax `(#EEEEEE)`, those bytes are in order (RRGGBB).  But if you are using hex notation (*ie* `0x......`), it may depend on the endianness of your system.  Many computers around are little-endian, so the actual value `0x112233` would be represented in memory as `33221100`.

Finally, the representation in memory depends on the device that is displaying that colour.  It may want bytes in the order `B-G-R` or it may want `R-G-B`.